# System.Net.WebRequest doesn't have Accept property on monotouch

Tags: c#, mono, httpwebrequest, xamarin.ios, webrequest

I'm trying to write some code for Monotouch which interfaces with a REST API which relies on the Accept header being set properly. If I try to do this in Monotouch I get the message:

```
Type 'System.Net.WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Request'...
```

Despite the fact that the property [appears in the API docs](http://api.xamarin.com/monodoc.ashx?link=P%3aSystem.Net.HttpWebRequest.Accept).

It's only my first day with Monotouch so maybe I'm missing something obvious... Any ideas?

Comment: The error message complains about 'Request', not 'Accept'.

Comment: I'm assuming you *didn't* copy/paste that error message verbatim (as it's `System.Net`, not `System.New`) but provided I'm wrong, it looks like you're trying to do something like `someRequest.Request.Accept` instead of just `someRequest.Accept` (as the error message indicates a missing member called `Request`, not `Accept`).

Comment: Your link goes to the Mono documentation, not the MonoTouch documentation. Are you sure it is supported? I would start the [documentation root](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios) and ensure that it is supported.

Comment: Sorry - the error was typed out in a rush (is there any way to copy a compilation error from the tooltips in MonoDevelop?). @poupou deciphered my mess though and gave the correct answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[System.Net.WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) has no `Accept` property, never did, never will ;-)

You're likely missing a typecast to [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) which does provide an [Accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept.aspx) property (because it make sense for HTTP, not FTP, file...).

This is supported by **MonoTouch** but if it was not (e.g. another header) then you could try to use the Headers property to add it manually.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was - I was implicitly typing the variable and had assumed that `HttpWebRequest.Create` returned a `HttpWebRequest! Funnily enough I went to bed just after posting this last night and the same answer occurred to me as I was falling asleep :)

Comment: Oh my god. You are a hero among men.